# chaining the same noun with の

Tags: word-choice

I heard a song going 本当の本当の本当の気持ち. The question is, what does this do? Does it strengthen the noun or is it ungrammatical? Or another example: 絶対の絶対

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *what does this do?*

Well, emotionally, it emphasizes 本当 or 絶対 as many times as it repeats, just similar to "so so dumb" and "very very very important" in English.

And grammatically, it *is* valid. 本当の本当の本当の気持ち can be parsed simply as `[true [true [true feeling]]]`, except what it denotes is not really apparent. It also reminds me of wordplays like ～なくなくなくなくない？, which has nothing ungrammatical, but redundant because double negative just yields positive. Incidentally, it's only an extended version of ～なくない？ in practice, regardless of parity.